How can I optimize the performance of a large React application with multiple state updates?
I'm working on a large React application that has several components with frequent state updates. I've noticed that the performance is starting to degrade, especially when there are multiple components updating their state simultaneously. Here are some specific issues I'm encountering:
• Frequent Re-renders: Some components re-render more often than necessary, even when their props or state haven't changed.
• Complex State Management: Managing state across different components is becoming increasingly difficult and affecting performance.
• Inefficient Use of Hooks: I'm using useState() and useEffect() extensively, and I'm concerned that my implementation might not be optimal.
Here is a simplified version of my code to illustrate the issue:
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const ExpensiveComponent = React.memo(({ data }) => {
  console.log('ExpensiveComponent re-render');
  return <div>{data}</div>;
});

const ParentComponent = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [data, setData] = useState('Initial Data');

  useEffect(() => {
    // Simulate an async data fetch
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const result = await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve('Fetched Data'), 2000));
      setData(result);
    };

    fetchData();
  }, [count]);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>Increment Count</button>
      <ExpensiveComponent data={data} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default ParentComponent;


There is CODE REVIEW@SE - please read up on cross-posting.
